# Drupal article Editor like hubpages and infobarrel

Tags: drupal, editor, drupal-7, article

Is there any article editor like hubpages.com in drupal 7 ? 
Editors like hubpages and infobarrel use drag and drop capsules , it is very prof to use and easy also

Answer (score 0):

Use the module [wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), and after enabling it, go to its settings page "admin/config/content/wysiwyg".

There you'll find a list of all available wysiwyg editors under "Installation instructions" section.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Im not asking about wysiwyg , Im asking about the draggable capsules

Comment: can u give me a screenshot or a live sample of what u r trying to do?!

Comment: here is the hubpages editor in this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=EnwkAy8nrz8#t=52s